# JFrame in remote between JDK 5 (Server) and 6 (Client - VisualVM)

Tags: serialization, jframe, java, jmx, visualvm

So I have a little trouble on the opening of a JFrame. I searched extensively on the net, but I really can not find a solution ...

I explained the situation:

I need to develop an application that needs to retrieve information tracking application while meeting new safety standards. For that I use JMX that allows monitoring and VisualVM to see these information.

I therefore I connect without problems (recently ^ ^) to JMX since VisualVM.

There is thus in a VisualVM plugin for recovering information on MBean, including those on Methods (Operations tab in the plugin).
This allows among others to stop a service or create an event.

My problem then comes when I try to display a result of statistics.
In fact, I must show, at the click of a button from the list of methods in the "Operations", a window with a table in HTML (titles, colors and everything else).

For that I use a JFrame:

```
public JFrame displayHTMLJFrame(String HTML, String title){
        JFrame fen = new JFrame();
        fen.setSize(1000, 800);
        fen.setTitle(title);

        JEditorPane pan = new JEditorPane();
        pan.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        pan.setEditable(false);

        pan.setText(HTML);
        fen.add(pan);
        return fen;
    }
```

I call it in my method:

```
public JFrame displayHtmlSqlStatOK_VM(){
        return displayHTMLJFrame(displaySQLStat(sqlStatOK, firstMessageDate), "SqlStatOK");
    }
```

The method must therefore giving me back my JFrame, but she generates an error:

```
Problem invoking displayHtmlSqlStatOK_VM : java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested 

exception is:
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JFrame; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 

-5208364155946320552, local class serialVersionUID = -2386951414768123374
```

I saw on the internet that this was a version problem (Serialization), and I believe strongly that it comes from the fact that I have this:

Server - JDK5 <----> Client (VisualVM) - JDK6

Knowing that I can not to change the server version (costs too important ...) as advocated by some sites and forums.

My question is as follows:

Can I display this damn window keeping my current architecture (JDK5 server side and client side JDK6)?

I could maybe force the issue? Tell him that there's nothing bad that can run my code? Finally I'm asking him but he does not answer me maybe to you he will tell you ... (Yes I crack ^^).

Thank you very much to those who read me and help me!

If you need more info do not hesitate.

**EDIT**

The solution to my problem might be elsewhere, because in fact I just want a table with minimal formatting (this is just for viewing application for an  for an officer to have his little table him possibly putting critical data in red...).

But I have nowhere found a list of types that I can return with VisualVM ... This does not however seem to me too much to ask.

After I had thought of a backup solution, which would be to create a temporary HTML file and open it automatically in the browser, but right after that is perhaps not very clean ... But if it can work ^^

I am open to any area of ​​research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well good I found myself, as a great :)

Thank you bye!

..........

Just kidding of course I will give the solution that I found ^ ^

So here's what I did:

My display to be done on the client (normal...) my code to display a JFrame that I had set up on the server was displayed obviously ... On the server xD

I didn't want to change the customer (VisualVM) to allow users maximum flexibility. However I realized that to display my HTML table to be rendered usable (with colors and everything) I had to change the client (as JMX does not support the type JFrame as type back an operation).

My operation running from the MBeans plugin for VisualVM, it was necessary that I find the source code for it to say "Be careful if you see that I give you the HTML you display it in a JFrame".

Here is my approach:

## - Get the sources

The link SVN to get sources VisualVM is as follows:

https: //svn.java.net/svn/visualvm~svn/branches/release134

If like me you have trouble with the SVN client includes in NetBeans because you are behind a proxy, you can do it by command line:

```
svn --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=MY_PROXY_HOST --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=MY_PROXY_PORT checkout https: //svn.java.net/svn/visualvm~svn/branches/release134 sources-visualvm
```

Putting you on your destination folder of course (cd C:\Users\me\Documents\SourcesVisualVM example).

## - Adding the platform VisualVM

NetBeans needs the platform VisualVM to create modules (plugins) for it. For this, go to "Tools" -> "NetBeans Platforms".

Then click "Add Platform ..." at the bottom left of the window and select the folder to the bin downloaded at this address: http:// visualvm.java.net/download.html

You should have this:

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/543268screen1.png

## - Adding sources in the workspace (NetBeansProjects)

Copy/paste downloaded sources (SVN from the link above) to your NetBeans workspace (by default in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects).

## - Ouverture du projet du plugin MBeans

In NetBeans, right click in the Project Explorer (or go to the menu "Files") and click "Open Project ...".
You will then have a list of projects in your workspace.
Open the project "mbeans" found in "release134" -> "Plugins", as below:

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/310487screen2.png

## - Changing the file "platform.properties"

To build plugin you must define some variables for your platform.
To do this, open the file **platform.properties** in the directory **release134\plugins\nbproject** of your workspace.
Replace the content (by changing the paths compared to yours):

```
cluster.path=\
    C:\\Program Files\\java6\\visualvm_134\\platform:\
    C:\\Program Files\\java6\\visualvm_134\\profiler

# Deprecated since 5.0u1; for compatibility with 5.0:
disabled.clusters=
nbjdk.active=default
nbplatform.active=VisualVM_1.3.4
suite.dir=${basedir}

harness.dir= C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.1.2\\harness
```

## - Changing the class XMBeanOperations

To add our feature (displaying an HTML table), you must change the class that processes operations, namely the class **XMBeanOperations** in package **com.sun.tools.visualvm . modules.mbeans**.

At line 173, replace:

```
if (entryIf.getReturnType() != null &&
                            !entryIf.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE.getName()) &&
                            !entryIf.getReturnType().equals(Void.class.getName()))
                        fireChangedNotification(OPERATION_INVOCATION_EVENT, button, result);
```

By :

```
if (entryIf.getReturnType() != null &&
                            !entryIf.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE.getName()) &&
                            !entryIf.getReturnType().equals(Void.class.getName())) {
                        if (entryIf.getReturnType() instanceof String) {
                            String res = result + "";
                            if (res.indexOf("<html>") != -1) {
                                JFrame frame = displayHTMLJFrame(res, button.getText());
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            else
                                fireChangedNotification(OPERATION_INVOCATION_EVENT, button, result);
                        } else
                            fireChangedNotification(OPERATION_INVOCATION_EVENT, button, result);
                    }
```

With the method of creating the JFrame that you place above "void performInvokeRequest (final JButton button)" for example:

```
// Display a frame with HTML code
public JFrame displayHTMLJFrame(String HTML, String title){
        JFrame fen = new JFrame();
    fen.setSize(1000, 800);
    fen.setTitle(title);

    JEditorPane pan = new JEditorPane();
    pan.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
    pan.setEditable(false);

    pan.setText(HTML);
    fen.add(pan);
    return fen;
}
```

We can see that we already did a test on the return type, if it is a String which is returned, if the case, if we see in this string the balise , then we replace the result of the click by opening a JFrame with the string you put in, what makes us display our HTML code!

## - Creating a .nbm

The file .nbm is the deployment file of your plugin. Simply right-click your project (in the Project Explorer) and click on "Create NBM".
Your file .nbm will be created in the folder "build" the root of your project.

## - Installing the plugin in VisualVM

To install your plugin, you must just go in VisualVM, go into "Tools" -> "Plugins" tab and then "Downloaded", click "Add Plugins ...". Select your plugin .nbm then click "Install". Then follow the instructions.

**Useful Sources**

http: //docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/

http: //visualvm.java.net/"]http://visualvm.java.net/

http: //visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html (Créer un plugin VisualVM avec NetBeans)

Thank you very much for your help Tomas Hurka ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending instance javax.swing.JFrame over the JMX connection - this is a bad idea.

Comment: Mmmh ok... And how do I view an HTML table with VisualVM? I tried to return a string, or an Arraylist, but the result is really not workable... :/

Comment: You need to provide more info - what kind of data do you want to display? Maybe you can use Tracer plugin with custom probes.

Comment: I want display an HTML Table :

    <p>06/08/12 17:24:51     Tableau des requetes excecutees en MOINS de 2000 ms.     Premier message recu le  <p>
    <table align="center" border=1 width=100% cellpadding=3>
    <tr>
      <th>Request ID</th>
      <th>Req. counter</th>
      <th>Average in ms</th>
      <th>Minimum in ms</th>
      <th>Maximum in ms</th>
      <th>Date of maximum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>...
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#00CC66">
      <td align="center">TOTAL</td>
      <td align="center">0</td>
      <td align="center">0</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

Comment: Scuse me for syntax... I can not do better in the "comment"

Comment: It seems to be that you can use CompositeData http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeData.html to send data from your application.

Comment: Thanks I look at it this morning in fact...
But I can not use HTML formatting so? No redirection is possible afterwards?